# Remove recently used emojis from Gboard

Tags: gboard

After switching from Samsung S7 Edge to Poco X3 NFC, although both on Android, I can't figure out how to remove recently used emojis, which is on Gboard.

I searched a lot but nothing related to Poco X3 NFC. The MIUI is 12.0.8

How to remove them from the keyboard?

Comment: clear data and cache of keyboard in settings >> apps >> gboard. i'd rather suggest to go for a keyboard which supports incognito mode like swiftkey

Answer (score 1):

None of the trusted keyboards support this feature.
Start afresh after clearing data and cache of the app - Settings >> Apps >> G Board.
Then use incognito mode on keyboard if it supports. Microsoft SwiftKey has incognito mode. IDK about GBoard.

Comment: I agree not many keyboards are not "trusted", but I don't think I would put either Google's Gboard or Microsoft's SwiftKey in the "trusted" category.  Clear their data and cache and then use either for a couple weeks.  The amount of data that they will store during that time is nothing short of staggering.  Then try an open-source keyboard with similar functionality, and one can see the open-source keyboards will not store all that data.  I have yet to see anyone successfully explain what Google's Gboard and Microsoft's SwiftKey are really collecting/storing/transmitting.

Comment: I used the word 'trusted' based on "Contains ads" thing. I used to like some keyboard apps like fleksy but it has ads now. I know Google and MS are collecting data but just hoping that they are not selling it.

Comment: I had a similar experience.  I can't exactly remember the name of my old favorite keyboard app, but I think it was called Chrooma.  What I do remember is that it was great, and then they turned it into a promotion-filled mess.